# iOS: Setting NSURLRequest without creating NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

Is there any way to designate a timeout for a method like:

```
NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
if(data)
   //dostuffwithdata
else
   NSLog(@"ERROR");
```

I know how to create a NSURLConnection and Delegate with a timeout set for the NSURLRequest - but its messy and for the sake of my program it doesn't matter that it will stall on the dataWithContentOfURL line - so I'd rather a simpler solution if its available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NSURLConnection` method `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`. It returns an `NSData` object, and you can configure the timeout using an `NSMutableURLRequest`.